# jQuery: игнорировать все внутренние тэги в DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

```
var mytext = jQuery('img.hovered').closest('.post_block').find('.tfish').text();
```

Возможно, в DIV **.tfish** будет еще два элемента: `<p class="citation">Случайный контент</p>` и `<blockquote class="ipsBlockquote built">Случайный контент</blockquote`

Мне нужно игнорировать все вышеуказанные классы с контентом и брать только оставшиеся текст:

```
alert(mytext);
```

Пытался так, но получается не совсем так, как я хочу:

```
var mytext = jQuery('img.hovered').closest('.post_block').find('.tfish').clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

Вероятно, потому что:

> Возможно, в DIV **.tfish** будет еще два элемента...

Как очистить текст от всех содержащихся в нём тегов?

```
<div class="post_block">
 <div class="post entry-content tfish">
  <p class="citation">
    Возможно будет
  </p>
  <blockquote class="ipsBlockquote built">
    Возможно будет
  </blockquote>
  <p>1 Текст который надо брать</p>
  <p>2 Текст который надо брать</p>
  <p>Может быть будет еще много текст</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А сам текст, который надо достать находится непосредственно в .tfish? То есть, я понимаю, надо только из этого класса брать текст, игнорируя текст во всех остальных потомках?

Comment: Я внес изменение в первый пост. Вы это имели ввиду?

Comment: Так немного понятнее. Значит надо брать только текст в элементах не имеющих классов? Потому что, если брать ВЕСЬ текст везде подходит просто .text(). http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: **Значит надо брать только текст в элементах не имеющих классов?**
Да.

Comment: var mytext = jQuery('img.hovered').closest('.post_block').find('.tfish p:not([class])').map(function(k,i){return i.textContent});

Comment: Уже что то получилось :)
`var mytext = jQuery('img.hovered').closest('.post_block').find('.tfish ').find("p:not([class]").text();`
С этим кодым получилось игнорировать **<p class="citation">Случайный контент</p>**
Нужно еще игнорировать это **<blockquote class="ipsBlockquote built">Случайный контент</blockquote>** и на этом все :)

Comment: Сделал так:

`var mytext = jQuery('img.hovered').closest('.post_block').find('.tfish > p').text();`

Игнорируется `blockquote class="ipsBlockquote built">Случайный контент</blockquote`

Но, остается `<p class="citation">Случайный контент</p>`

Comment: p:not([class]) выберет только абзацы без класса. blockquote не должен попасть в это, если он сам не лежит в p

Answer (score 1):

Я Написал по Вашим последним правкам. Только вывел в консоль, потому что если через alert(), то окно будет выводиться три раза, одно за другим. Если необходимо именно в alert() вывести, надо будет немного подправить функцию.

```js
var mytext = $('.post_block').find('.tfish').children();
mytext.each(function() {
    if (!$(this).attr('class')) {
        console.log($(this).text())
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="post_block">
    <div class="post entry-content tfish">
       <p class="citation">
          Возможно будет
       </p>
       <blockquote class="ipsBlockquote built">
          Возможно тоже будет
       </blockquote>
       <p>
          1 Текст который надо брать
       </p>
       <p>
          2 Текст который надо брать
       </p>
       <p>
          Может быть будет еще много текст
       </p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Зависает страница.

Comment: посмотрите в консоли почему зависает. Я сделал этот код для наглядности в stackoverflow. Попробуйте нажать "выполнить код" и посмотреть что получается. У вас происходит событие скорее всего при наведении мыши на jQuery('.imgHovered'). Значит надо будет искать, начиная jQuery('.imgHovered'). Соответственно  применить к элементу, на котором мышь в данный момент находится.

Comment: не $('.imgHovered'), а $('img.hovered')

Answer (score 1):

Получился:

```
jQuery('img.hovered').closest('.post_block').find('.tfish > p:not([class])').text();
```

За идею спасибо **@Anon**

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте регуляркой:

```
mytext.replace (/<\/?[^>]+>/g, '');
```

Заменяет все html-теги на пустые строки

Comment: `var mytext = jQuery('img.hovered').closest('.post_block').find('.tfish').text().replace (/<\/?[^>]+>/g, '');` 
Не работает.

Comment: @ErekleMaziashvili, а что получается вместо того, что нужно?

Comment: Все равно берет текст из вышеуказанные классы.

Answer (score 0):

Можно и так

```js
jQuery('img.hovered').closest('.post_block').find('.tfish *').remove();
var a = jQuery('img.hovered').closest('.post_block').find('.tfish');
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, я не понял...

Comment: изменил ответ. то что вы хотели?